# wifi hotspot start up

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I am using my Ubuntu LTS 18.04 to hotspot an internet connection to various other devices, but I would like this to be the default configuration, but when I restart the system I currently have to switch the hotspot on again each time.

How can I make the hotspot the default setting for my wifi device?

Comment: correct yes I selected the option to switch the hotspot on and share the wired internet connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Workaround***

Ok, Instead of Turning the Hotspot on via GUI Every time.. you can add a Startup Applications Preference for your Hotspot Connection..

to add the command to Startup Applications Preferences, you need to know your connection name..

to know the connection name..

either run `nm-connection-editor` and look for the required connection

[image]

or once the Hotspot is on, run `nmcli device show | grep GENERAL.CONNECTION:`

Example:

```
parrot@i7-4770U:~$ nmcli device show | grep GENERAL.CONNECTION:
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     MyHotSpot
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
parrot@i7-4770U:~$
```

So the required connection name is `MyHOtSpot`

to turn on and off this connection, the below commands are used..

```
nmcli connection up MyHotSpot
nmcli connection down MyHotSpot
```

[image]

So to turn on the HotSpot at every boot..

add the command `nmcli connection up MyHotSpot` to Startup Application Preferences like this

[image]

the below pic is a automatic gnome-screenshot with delay of 10 secs after a reboot which shows Hotspot is On.

[image]