# Turn on Wi-Fi hotspot using command line on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

Is there any way to enable a pre-configured Wi-Fi hotspot from a shell script/command line without going to `Settings` > `Wi-Fi` > `(settings icon)` > `Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot...` > `Turn On`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1146694/739431

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/324785/507051) has a script which does something very similar: It creates the AP interface and shows how to bring it up and down. Bringing an existing interface up and down should be as easy as `ip link set INTERFACE up/down`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @PRATAP's answer:

```
nmcli connection up <SSID>
```

Where `<SSID>` is likely `Hotspot` (can check this by running `nm-connection-editor` or going to `Settings` > `Wi-Fi` > `(settings icon)` > `Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network...` > `Connection`).

`nmcli connection up`/`down` also works for normal (non-hotspot) networks.

Comment: Hotspot is not the device's SSID but the network's profile name.

Comment: Where can I setup hotspot config without using GUI? `nm-connection-editor` requires GUI

Comment: @gkucmierz `nmcli connection show`